# The question about "failedTx set" after add TX to new block done

Tags: mempool

Try to understand the whole process of mempool working. There is one thing I can't figure out: after add TX to new block done, how to deal with those TXs in failedTx set (those TXs add to failedTx during the new block creating process)? 
Could anyone help me? Thanks.